# Integration of $\frac{1}{dx}$ in physical applications

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

$$\frac{1}{dc} = \frac{dx}{εx}$$

That's what I was left with when I was finding the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor with non-uniform dielectric in it. I just needed to find $c$ (capacitance) for this problem where the total distance ($D$) was also given.

But I don't think this integration which is $$∫\frac{1}{dc} = ∫\frac{dx}{εx}$$ [$ε$ is constant]
can be solved. Can it be? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you're mixing $d$=distance with the differential $d$?  $dx$ in the differential sense is infinitesimal, so if it's not balanced by another one, it's basically just 0.  So if your $d$s are differentials, you're basically saying that infinity=0.

Comment: is $d$ the same on both sides of the equation? or do we have $dc$ and  $dx$ both as differentials?

Comment: oh no, d represents the differentiation's d (ie dx). Sorry for confusion, changed d(distance) to D. See edit @DrXorile

Comment: Latter assumption is true..@tired

Comment: Then you're equation is saying that $0=\infty$

Comment: how is the quantity $1/dc$ defined?

Comment: Ya, its undefined, so just tell me how should I find c ? @tired

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we have a parallel plate capacitor with area $A$ and thickness $d$.  We will establish a coordinate system in which the plates are on the planes $x=0$ and $x=d$.  Assume that the permittivity varies as a function of $x$ so that $\epsilon = \epsilon(x)$.

Now, partition the interval $[0,d]$ into $N$ equal-sized subintervals of size $\Delta x=d/N$.  The $n$th subinterval in $[x_{n-1},x_n]$ where $x_0=0$ and $x_N=d$.

For large $N$, the capacitance $C_n$ of the $n$th subinterval can be approximated by

$$C_n\approx \frac{\epsilon(x_n)A}{\Delta x}$$

We know that the aggregate structure is comprised of a series arrangement of the capacitors $C_n$.  Therefore the total capacitance $C$ satisfies the equation

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{C}&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{C_n}\\\\
&\approx \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\epsilon(x_n)A}\Delta x \tag 1
\end{align}$$

If we take the limit as $N\to \infty$, and recognize that the right-hand side of $(1)$ is a Riemann sum, then we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{1}{C}=\int_0^d \frac{1}{\epsilon(x)A}\,dx}$$

Comment: Would the anonymous down voter care to comment?